# Call custom section on page load customer/section/load/?sections=customsection

Tags: magento2

I would like to call 
`customer/section/load/?sections=customsection` on page load. Similar how the cart is being called on page load.
[image]

I've already added section data in the frontend/di.xml

```
 <type name="Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPoolInterface">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="sectionSourceMap" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="customsection" xsi:type="string">{Class}</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

However, the "customsection" is not being called unlike with "cart" and "quotecart"